# How to extend a Button using Androidx

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-appcompat, androidx

I seem to have run into a classic Android gotcha: use a deprecated api, or an api that doesn't work yet..

I've migrated my project to use AndroidX rather than the AppCompat support libraries.

And now I want to extend `android.widget.Button` to make a custom Button. However, Android Studio 3.5.3 won't have it, saying I should instead extend `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton`. Which is part of the now-deprecated support libraries - and for which there should, therefore, presumably be an AndroidX equivalent. But I can't find such a thing....

Is there a convenient cross-reference tool to help us find AndroidX equivalents to all the old support library classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can extend one of these:

- `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton` provided by the material components library
- `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton` provided by the androidx appcompat library
- `android.widget.Button`

You can use the androidx [class Mappings](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings) to check the current mappings from the old support library packages to the new androidx packages.